# Возникает ошибка vk_api.exceptions.AuthError: Unknown API auth error python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

В последнее время при авторизации через библиотеку `vk_api` на python стала появляться такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    vk.auth()
  File "C:\Users\Mikk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 178, in auth
    self._auth_cookies(reauth=reauth)
  File "C:\Users\Mikk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 209, in _auth_cookies
    self._api_login()
  File "C:\Users\Mikk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 468, in _api_login
    raise AuthError('Unknown API auth error')
vk_api.exceptions.AuthError: Unknown API auth error
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит из-за того, что при авторизации библиотека по умолчанию использует app-id=6222115, а это приложение в данный момент заблокированно: при переходе по ссылке авторизации ( https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6222115&scope=1073737727&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token&revoke=1 ) мне выдают ошибку `{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"application is disabled"}`.

Вариант обхода есть, и очень простой - достаточно при создании объекта `VkApi` подставить другой параметр `app-id`, например, 2685278

То есть:

```
vk = vk_api.VkApi(login='login',password='password',app_id=2685278)
vk.auth();
```